# Sequential filtering IQueryable instance

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

Quick question about using IQueryable objects. Can I do something like that and if not - what is the alternative way?

```
IQueryable<Item> q = this.ObjectContext.items;

q = q.Where(i => i.price > 100);

...

q = q.Where(i => i.class_name.Contain("apple"));
```

**Update**: Here is full code of my function (may be I'm missing something):

```
public IQueryable<item> Getitem(string filter)
{
    // filtering by user departments
    IQueryable<item> pre_q = from t_item in this.ObjectContext.items
        join t_useritems in this.ObjectContext.user_to_item on
        t_item.number equals t_useritems.number
        where t_useritems.user_name == this.userName
        select t_item;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        QueryFilter qf = new QueryFilter(filter);
        string _excludeClass = qf.GetPropertyValueByName("excludeClass");
        string _excludeSubcat = qf.GetPropertyValueByName("excludeSubcat");
        string _searchBy = qf.GetPropertyValueByName("searchby");
        string _search = qf.GetPropertyValueByName("search");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_excludeClass))
            pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.class_name != _excludeClass);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_excludeSubcat))
            pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.subcat_name != _excludeSubcat);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_search))
        {
            if (_searchBy == "number")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.number.Contains(_search));
            else if (_searchBy == "description")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.description.Contains(_search));
            else if (_searchBy == "class_name")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.class_name.Contains(_search));
            else if (_searchBy == "cat_name")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.cat_name.Contains(_search));
            else if (_searchBy == "subcat_name")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.subcat_name.Contains(_search));
            else if (_searchBy == "all_fields")
                pre_q = pre_q.Where(i => i.number.Contains(_search) ||
                  i.description.Contains(_search) ||
                  i.class_name.Contains(_search) ||
                  i.cat_name.Contains(_search) ||
                  i.subcat_name.Contains(_search));
            }
        }
    }
    return pre_q.OrderBy(i => i.number);
}
```

Essentially what's happening - I pass excludeClass filter and some search text filter. After applying excludeClass I can see that number of records is correct, however when I after apply search filter - it basically reset already filtered items and they are getting back in the result.

Comment: The update is good, but still need to see some kind of "here's my inputs, and here's my TSQL, look: this bit should be filtered, but it isn't"

Comment: This method is called with excludeFilter=someName, searchBy=number, search=someText. If searchBy and search are not set it works fine - I'm getting back only records where class_name is not someName. But if I pass searchBy/search then I'm getting back records with class_name == someName as well. Where do I get TSQL?

Comment: a SQL trace would be a good start. If this was LINQ-to-SQL you can get it very trivially; with EF, just SQL profiler is simpler.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. But from looking at the code - you think it should work?

Comment: yes, I believe it should

Comment: It should work from an IQueryable perspective. Which version of EF are you using? Early versions had issues building the TSQL correctly in some cases. For profiling, you can cast the pre_q explicitly to an ObjectQuery and calling ToTraceString on it as follows: `Console.WriteLine(((ObjectQuery)pre_q).ToTraceString());`

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. Looks like I had some problems on the client end - just needed to have confirmation that EF should work this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. `IQueryable<T>` is "composable". That's fine. It will only evaluate the final composed query when you do something that needs the data, for example a `ToList()`, a `foreach`, or an aggregate such as `Count()`, `Max()`, etc. That pattern is pretty much how a lot of multi-field search screens work.

Comment: Hm... Why it doesn't work then? :) In my case it looks like after applying the second filter - first one goes away...

Comment: Hold on... You said count()? So if I add `trace(q.Count())` in between it will break it, right?

Comment: @sha how did you conclude that? Was the SQL that eventually went down, and how did you use the query? ('cos you haven't shown us that)

Comment: @sha no, that shouldn't "break" it - it will just execute the `Count()` with what is in the filter at the time.